# Вопрос по ProgressDialog (расположить по центру экрана)

Tags: java, android

Решил немного поменять стиль ProgressDialog, прописал в файле styles.xml

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/DialogWindowTitle</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogWindowTitle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

и в java-классе

```
 progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext(), R.style.MyTheme);
```

Проблема в том, что диалог стал появляться вверху экрана, а не по центру, как было до этого, видимо при переопределении стиля забыл указать параметр, который отвечает за это. Подскажите в чем проблема, спасибо.

Comment: Вы же диалог хотите, от темы диалога и наследуйтесь. AppCompat.Light.Dialog как-то там

Comment: да, все верно, <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"> , работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Ответ: необходимо было наследоваться от Dialog в моей теме

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
```